# Pipe Node CLI output to a file without changing it

Tags: node.js

I have a small JS file:

```bash
$ cat test-session.js
1 + 1
Math.cos(1)
```

If I pipe this through `node --interactive`, it executes it and shows both the input and output, much as you would if you ran the commands by hand:

```bash
cat test-session.js | node --interactive
Welcome to Node.js v18.8.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> 1 + 1
2
> Math.cos(1)
0.5403023058681398
> %
```

If I pipe this to a file or other command, it completely changes. The input lines are gone and, weirdly, the output lines show up with the `>`  prefix instead:

```bash
cat test-session.js | node --interactive | cat
Welcome to Node.js v18.8.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> 2
> 0.5403023058681398
> %
```

Is there a way to keep the interleaved input/output display and redirect *that* to a file?

(I realize this is a weird thing to want to do. The broader context is that this I want to check that node sessions published in a book or on a web site match reality, see [here](https://github.com/danvk/literate-ts/issues/117).)